# How to create eyeballs holes without messing up the mesh and the topology?

Tags: mesh, topology

How can I create this eye holes (the little black things around the eyes) Without messing up the topology? How may options do I have? I've alredy tried the Boolean Modifier

[image]

With Boolean Modifier:
[image]

Please answer with all the options. Thanks!

Comment: You have only one option - increase the density of the mesh around the eyes. It's too low poly. Look for "face topology" on the internet and adapt the density and edge flow to your model.

Comment: How do I increase the density? What  controls, i mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create more mesh lines around the eyes in order for there to be more points that Blender can use to maintain the form. Each vertex is a point on the mesh that Blender uses to calculate the surface area, so if you have too few vertices, it can only calculate the shape based on those few points. Add more mesh lines and use the vertices on them to give Blender more points to work with.

There are many ways to add more mesh. Listing them here is not possible. Play around with the various mesh tools and consult the documents for explanations on how to use them.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried Ctrl + R + 3 around the eyes, and it works!

Comment: You'll remember that useful tool and use it often.